# How to build multi-step-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux-form

Hello I come to seek your help because I would like to make a form multi step (11 steps) sua react native, knowing that it will test each input field, reset the form at the last step.

Each step will have a screen.

I think you have to change the states, and I also think that redux seems well suited for my case because the data is persistent but I know that redux can affect the performance of the application.

I'm a little lost, I'm not the way to go, would you have some leads?

I thank you in advance for your help and your answers.

**----------------------------------------------------- Update -----------------------------------------------------------------**

I've come a long way but I'm blocking at the validation of the fields, I followed the example "Form Wizard" redux-form doc(https://redux-form.com/6.4.3/examples/wizard/), but I do not see how to prevent navigation to the next screer when there is an error in entering the fields.

```
const Fields = [{
_id:1,
field:[
    {
        "name": 'Name',
    },
    {
        "name":'Age'
    }

 ]}, {

_id:2,
field:[
    {
        "name":'Email'
    }

]}, {

_id:3,
field : [
    {
        "name":'City'
    },
    {
        "name":'Countries'
    }
]}];

export default Fields;
```

My Component FormWizard.js :

```
class FormWizard extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    if(this.props.navigation.state.params === undefined) {
        this.page = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        this.page = this.props.navigation.state.params.page;
    }
}

_nextStep = (page, values) => {
    this.props.navigation.push("FormWizard", {page: this.page + 1});
    console.log('submitting from',values);
};

render() {
    const page  = this.page;
    return(
        <View>
            <DynamicForm
                page={page}
                nextStep={this._nextStep}
            />
        </View>
    )
}

}

export default FormWizard;
```

My Component DynamicForm.js :

```
const submit = values => {
console.log('submitting from', values);
};

const renderInput = ({ label, input: {onChange, ...restInput }, meta:{error, touched} }) => {
return <View>
    <TextField
        style={styles.input}
        label={label}
        onChangeText={onChange}
        {...restInput}
    />
    {touched && (error && (<Text style={{color: 'red'}}>{error}</Text>))}
</View>
};

const Form = props => {

const { handleSubmit, nextStep, page} = props;

return <View>
    <Text>Etape : {page}</Text>
    {Fields[page].field.map((el, index) => (
        <View key={index}>
            <Field
                label={el.name}
                name={el.name}
                component={renderInput}
            />
        </View>
    ))}

    {page === Fields.length - 1 ? (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSubmit(submit)}>
            <Text style={styles.button}>Submit</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    ) : (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={nextStep}>
            <Text style={styles.button}>Suivant</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )}

</View>;
};

   const FormWizard = reduxForm({
       form:'test',
       validate
   })(Form);

export default FormWizard;
```

I am really sorry if the code is poorly formatted, I try to solve the problem, thank you in advance for your help and your answers.

Comment: Could you, as an example, add a more specific case, just complex enough to illustrate what you would like to create?

Comment: I would like now to be able to perform a validation of the fields in the form multi step under redux-form, but I do not know how to manage it with react navigation, I updated my post by adding my code.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a good look into redux-form.
https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/
There is a lot of documentation on it including examples.

Redux-Form is very powerful and very customizable.
The example Wizard Form is probably the scenario you're looking for:
https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/wizard/

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer, I intended to use it but I read that the project was abandoned for a while, major bugs, can affect performance.

 Maybe it's been changing since then, I do not know and I was not sure if it's necessary for what I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

The application will integrate a multi step form, the form will have 11 steps, if I have to create a component for each step, I will have a lot of it.

Good finally I used cheat-shape, what I wish to do is to edit the form in one screen, as soon as I press the next button.

For her I first tried to edit a topic I called page, I would like to change the value of this about as soon as I go push on a single screen.